# Flutter :: Camera plugin issue :: Application is not working in android but it is suitable for iOS

Tags: flutter, android-camera

I am new to flutter development basically I am an ios developer,

While I am working on a new project in a flutter doing for the profile update screen
I have added a camera plugin for dependencies to get camera third-party to use both in ios android. So when it uses the ios application is running smoothly without showing an error but the android application showing some errors as follows

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'camera'.

 * Try:
 Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 1s

 Exception: The plugin camera could not be built due to the issue above.
```

can anyone tell what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: Which is the plugin you are trying to use on the project?

Comment: Can you provide a plugin you are using, also try with real device it may also cause because of simulator/emulator.

Comment: but ios application the dependency "camera" works fine. There is no issue while loading in the ios simulator
the  only issue with android emulators

Comment: @AraKurghinyan  "camera"

Comment: You could probably run `flutter clean`, then do a `pub get`, then try running the android installation via `flutter run --release`

Comment: @DarShan I have tried   flutter clean pub get  flutter run --release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compileSdkVersion in build.gradle it ma about compileSdkVersion. Should be updated 29 or higher or
If you set 'org.gradle.configureondemand=true' in 'gradle.properties'，please change to false.

Comment: build.gradle is checked and change the properties,  not working in android

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing **compileSdkVersion** in build.gradle to a higher version like from 28 to 29 or 30?

Comment: yes it already in 29 changed to 28 and 30 but not installing in android

Answer (score 0):

I do see similar Github issues where some had success by updating classpath to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1` eg: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/208. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this to solve my issue

in androidmanifest.xml my user-permission was in wrong place and marked as **red**
moved outside  and worked.